# Is "was always with you" or "had always been with you" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, backshifting

> 1. In those days wherever you went I **had always been** with you like a shadow.
> 2. In those days wherever you went I **was always** with you like a shadow.

Which one is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2):

"I had always been with you like a shadow until you noticed me". This would makes sense when using the past perfect tense. In this case we refer to an earlier past situation before another situation took place. Just think of it as the past of the past. Otherwise, the simple past is used when everything happens together in the past at any given time.(i.e. simultaneously).
I'm from Canada where we normally in everyday life avoid using the past perfect so as to not sound confusing and verbose. Just simplify to past simple!
Unless of course, you're writing a "gothic novel":) Cheers!
Roman

Answer (score 1):

> In those days wherever you went I was always with you like a shadow

The second one is correct

Answer (score 0):

The "had ... been" form is the past perfect form of "to be." Its use is to date the time of the "being" to a time even before "those days."
The "was" form means that the "being" was contemporaneous with "those days."

Comment: Which one is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 0):

I don't pretend to be an expert, but to me your examples don't say the same thing, but I think I get what you're going for and the second example accomplishes it.

"`In those days wherever you went I had always been with you like a shadow`" You establish we are talking about a time in the past. Let's code name it "those days". Then you talk about a time before that. Up until those days the person had always been there, but you don't comment on whether they are there during "those days". Even if that was your goal the sentence wouldn't work due to the transition between "those days" and the time before it. If you goal is to establish presence before "those days" you will need to reword. Perhaps something like "`In those days I had always been with you wherever you were going.`".

"`In those days wherever you went I was always with you like a shadow`" You establish a time, and then establish your presence during that time. This example doesn't mention a time before hand. If your goal is to establish presence during "those days" as I assume it is then this is the correct example.